# how to make sure some piece of code is executed before all other codes in java script?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in javascript and what makes me so confused in the order of operations in Javascript.

lets suppose I have a following code:

```
var myArray = [];
function getArray(x){
var _array = [];
.... {the code here is pretty big}
return _array;
}
myArray = getArray(1);
```

and rest of the code are all based on myArray. Unfortunately, using this code sometimes myArray is not set in time so the rest of code doesn't work properly. Is there anyway that I can make sure the rest of the code is executed when myArray is set properly?

Thanks,

Amir.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but relevant. Arrays are passed as a pointer to the first element in most languages, including js. Try this `function getArray(x, myArray){;} var myArray = []; getArray(1, myArray)`. Of course, it's up to your taste.

Comment: Ben - if the concept of a "first element" applies at all to ECMAScript arrays, I'd expect it to be the value referenced by index 0, not 1. Arrays are just objects, their properties have no particular order (and can be shown to not have any particular order), just like other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place it at the top of the js file or html before any other javascript and it will execute first. This assumes you don't have it wrapped in some sort of delay like `setTimeout` or jQuery's document ready function.

JS executes as it is loaded by the web browser, so the order it appears in determines the order it executes in relative to other JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
> var myArray = [];
```

There are two phases to javascript processing: the first processes all declarations, the second executes the code. So regardless of where *myArray* is declared, it will be declared before any code is executed.

When code execution begins, statements are executed in sequence so *myArray* is assigned an empty array before the following code is executed.

```
>  function getArray(x) { 
>    var _array = []; ....
>    // the code here is pretty big
>     return _array;
>  }
```

Similarly, *getArray* will also be defined before any code is run.

```
>  myArray = getArray(1);
```

This replaces the array assigned to *myArray* above with whatever is returned by *getArray*.

If, from time to time, the value of *myArray* is not what you expect, then it is a consequence of whatever is being returned by *getArray*, so I would concentrate on that.